# Set Static Day and Previous Month GETDATE() SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following SQL statement sets the date for a particular column:

```
DATEDUE=convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103 )
```

However, its sets the current date such as  05/08/2015. What I wish to do is to have it in the same **dd/mm/yyyy** format but to set the day to the 15th and the month to the previous month, so **05/08/2015** should be **15/07/2015** instead.

Comment: even if the current date is the 16th? you still want previous month?

Comment: btw.. you guys run a tough ship always setting the DueDate to a past Date ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
              DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) + 14
              ,103)

 Result: 15/07/2015
```

### Important Note

Since `DATEDUE` column is storing dates, you should really use the sql server `DATE` data type for storing date values in that column.

Answer (score 0):

if you decide you just need the most recent previous 15th of the month you can use this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
       DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()) - 
       (CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()) > 15 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 0)),
       103)
```

**`05/08/2015`** becomes **`15/07/2015`**  and  **`24/08/2015`** becomes **`15/08/2015`** instead of **`15/07/2015`**